# Issue with Bundling and Release mode

Tags: asp.net, webforms, bundling-and-minification, authorize-attribute

When ever i publish my web site with `debug="false"` mode and `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true`
the server returns the following exception for bundled scripts and styles while  requests are just for non authorized requests! But if I run application with `debug="true"` or user is logged in  (via forms authentication in release mode) the exception does not occur and every thins works just fine.

I think there should be a relation between bundling and authentication!! as the exception indicates.

What is wrong?

my bundling codes:

```
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        StyleBundle bundleStyles = new StyleBundle("~/bundles/styles/");
        bundleStyles.Include(
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.AdminSkin.css.reset_css,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.AdminSkin.css.common_css,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.AdminSkin.css.form_css,

            //do not move this line to blow
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.site.css.standard_css,

            "~" + Paths.Scripts.AdminSkin.css.standard_css,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.AdminSkin.css.special_pages_css,

            //"~" + Paths.Scripts.AdminSkin.css.simple_lists_css,
            //"~" + Paths.Scripts.AdminSkin.css.block_lists_css,
            //"~" + Paths.Scripts.AdminSkin.css.planning_css,
            //"~" + Paths.Scripts.AdminSkin.css.table_css,
            //"~" + Paths.Scripts.AdminSkin.css.calendars_css,
            //"~" + Paths.Scripts.AdminSkin.css.wizard_css,
            //"~" + Paths.Scripts.AdminSkin.css.gallery_css,

            "~" + Paths.Scripts.site.css.login_css,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.site.css.site_css,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.site.css.tables_css,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.site.css.standard_fa_css,


            "~" + Paths.Scripts.site.css.theme_selector_css,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.jquery_ui_1_9_2.css.redmond.jquery_ui_1_9_2_custom_css,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.ImageGallery.wt_rotator_css,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.ImageGallery.default_css,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.calendar.aqua.theme_css
            );

        ScriptBundle bundleScripts = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts/");
        bundleScripts.Include(
            //Admin Skin Scripts
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.AdminSkin.js.old_browsers_js,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.AdminSkin.js.libs.jquery_hashchange_js,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.AdminSkin.js.jquery_accessibleList_js,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.AdminSkin.js.searchField_js,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.AdminSkin.js.common_js,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.AdminSkin.js.standard_js,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.AdminSkin.js.jquery_tip_js,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.AdminSkin.js.jquery_contextMenu_js,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.AdminSkin.js.jquery_modal_js,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.AdminSkin.js.list_js,
            //"~" + Paths.Scripts.AdminSkin.js.libs.jquery_dataTables_min_js,

            //jquery plug ins
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.jquery_ui_1_9_2.js.jquery_ui_1_9_2_custom_js,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.jquery_cookie.jquery_cookie_js,


            "~" + Paths.Scripts.site.js.site_js,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.site.js.clock_js,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.site.js.size_js,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.site.js.cookie_manager_js,


            //devexpress related
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.site.js.devexpress_theme_js,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.site.js.devexpress_controls_js,

            //chart scripts
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.Highstock_1_2_5.highstock_src_modified_js,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.Highstock_1_2_5.exporting_js,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.Highstock_1_2_5.highcharts_more_js,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.site.js.chart_fa_js,

           //calendar scripts
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.calendar.jalali_js,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.calendar.calendar_js,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.calendar.calendar_setup_js,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.calendar.calendar_fa_js,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.calendar.calendar_en_js,

            //image gallery scripts
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.ImageGallery.js.jquery_wt_rotator_min_js,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.ImageGallery.js.jquery_easing_1_3_min_js,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.ImageGallery.js.preview_js
            );


        if (RequestCachedItems.Setting.UseGoogleMap)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            //leaflet map script
            bundleScripts.Include("~" + Paths.Scripts.leaflet_0_7.leaflet_src_js);
            //leaflet map style
            bundleStyles.Include("~" + Paths.Scripts.leaflet_0_7.leaflet_css, new CssRewriteUrlTransform());
        }

        ScriptBundle bundleLiveScripts = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/livescripts/");
        bundleLiveScripts.Include(
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.signalr.jquery_signalR_2_0_0_min_js,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.signalr.hubs_js,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.liveControls.connectionManager_js,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.liveControls.liveControls_js,
            "~" + Paths.Scripts.liveControls.liveTables_js
            );

        bundles.Add(bundleStyles);
        bundles.Add(bundleScripts);
        bundles.Add(bundleLiveScripts);

        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;

    }
```

the exception:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]    **System.Web.HttpContext.RequestRequiresAuthorization()
>   +18**    System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule.OnLeave(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs) +9606196
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +136    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69

Comment: This sounds like it has nothing to do with bundling, but that you have a problem getting a resource when the user is not logged in (the resource is null).

Comment: @MikeSmithDev, why it is null? and why it isn't when user gets logged in?

Comment: That is a question for your code.  I'm guessing it'd be something like `Paths.Scripts.AdminSkin` is null if user isn't logged in and/or user isn't Admin.

Comment: I've found my source of issue. thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` in `Global.ascx.cs`
and made `HttpContext.Current.User` null. I've commented that line and the problem is solved.

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket;
    ExtendedUser extendedUser;

    protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //cause of problem
        //HttpContext.Current.User = null;
        if (FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value);

                    using (UnitOfWork unit = new UnitOfWork())
                    {
                        if (ticket.Name == SecurityHelpers.SuperAdminUserName)
                        {
                            SecurityHelpers.GetSuperAdminUser(unit);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            extendedUser = SecurityHelpers.GetUser(unit, ticket);
                        }
                    }

                    if (extendedUser != null)
                    {
                        string[] roles = extendedUser.Group.GroupRoles.Select(a => a.Role.RoleName).ToArray();
                        HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(new MyFormsIdentity(extendedUser), roles);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // Decrypt method failed.
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //  throw new HttpException("Cookieless Forms Authentication is not " +
            //                          "supported for this application.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome!! I spend the whole day trying to sort this out from somebody elses "custom authorisation" code... They were setting the user to null allover the place. Removed all that code and it works just fine. Bundles load perfectly when logged out but cant view locked pages. Nice one! This was a difficult one to find... eventually combing the exception and mvc bundles led me to this +shisha!