# Global.asax Application_Error NullReference Exception

Tags: c#, webforms, global-asax

Asp.net web Forms
in my Global.asax 
i'm handling Application error 
i get Null Reference Exception 
Sender Global.asax 
i debugged all functions inside non of them return error
i'm sure it is from else where 
the problem that

```
Server.GetLastError()
```

Does not give information about the Error or the code giving the error
[image]

Comment: `Server.GetLastError()` is returning null l. That's why you are getting this error

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya no it isn't--look again! If it was null we would not obtain this stack trace.

Comment: Is that something you are looking for resource that your are not authorized, + can you please share the innerException please?

Comment: Yes you are right. `Server.GetLastError()` returns the error which itself is NullReferenceExeption. Thanks for pointing that out. @RegEdit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen if you use incompatible code in `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` or elsewhere in Global.ascx.cs.

See this answer for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21097374/1657610

If you have any code in `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` or elsewhere in Global.ascx.cs, try commenting it out to see if the issue goes away. If it goes away, selectively reenable the code until the issue returns. In this way you can isolate the issue to one or two lines of code. At this point, either the reason may become obvious, or an internet search specific to that code is likely to provide the explanation.

Comment: it was not the actual fix but it helped , removing HttpContext.Current.User = null; make me complete the debug , when it exists it stop the debugger at that line  ==> Thanks